# Fastest way to copy several 2-dimensional arrays into one 1-dimensional array (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array

I want to copy several 2-dimensional subarrays of 3-dimensional arrays (e.g. array1[n][rows][cols], ..., array4[n][rows][cols]), which are dynamically allocated (but with fixed length), into a 1-dimensional array (e.g. array[4*rows*cols]), which is statically allocated, in C. As there will be many rows and columns (e.g. 10000 rows and 500 columns), I was wondering which of the following three possibilities will be the fastest:

```
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
      for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
        array[i*cols+j]=array1[2][i][j];
      }
    }
    ...
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
      for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
        array[3*rows*cols+i*cols+j]=array4[2][i][j];
        }
    }
```

or

```
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
      for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
        array[i*cols+j]=array1[2][i][j];
      }
      ...
      for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
        array[3*rows*cols+i*cols+j]=array4[2][i][j];
      }
    }
```

or

```
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
      for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
        array[i*cols+j]=array1[2][i][j];
        ...
        array[3*rows*cols+i*cols+j]=array4[2][i][j];
      }
    }
```

Or is there even a faster way of performing this task in C (not C++)?

Thanks a lot! (I thought there should be a similar question already, but unfortunately did not find exactly what I was looking for. So, I am sorry if I missed such a question.)

Edit:
The reason for wanting to do this is the following: The information stored in those 2-dimensional (sub-)arrays has to be communicated via MPI. So, clients will do the above and the master (kind of) the other way round (i.e. 1-dimensional -> 2-dimensional). So, is there even a better way to do this overall?

Comment: What is the business reason for making the copy?   If you just need to iterate though some dimensions in a read only manner there may be other faster options.

Comment: I suspect that [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) is the way to go (if you **need** to copy the data).

Comment: Do you know anything about your hardware?  Can you set up a DMA?

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. I have just added some background. Moreover, I use (mp)icc -O3 ... to compile.
@ElliottFrisch: Can I use memcpy here as my array1, ... array4 are dynamically allocated, but array is not (and moreover, they are of different dimension?

Comment: @CarlNorum: Is DMA feasible here? What hardware info would be informative?

Comment: @CariBaur Yes, I do believe so.

Comment: @CariBaur, if you know about your hardware and how to use the DMA, it almost certainly would be helpful.  At the very least, your CPU can be off doing something else while the copy takes place.

Comment: The best way to get the answer it to try it ! It all depends on several factors such as memory footprint and cache/virtual memory responsiveness. Even with a deep knowledge of the machine architecture, it has become impossible to make reliable predictions. Usually, contiguous accesses are better than scattered accesses.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just keep the arrays in linear memory throughout your application and avoid the conversion.  You can use a simple macro if you want to keep the 2D indexing, but contiguous linear storage will usually perform better than "jagged array" dynamic 2D arrays.  Multiplication is generally cheaper than indirection, and the cache is happier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming linear arrays and the same dimensions (which would invalidate my answer):

This

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<cols;j++) {
    array[i*cols+j]=array1[2][i][j];
  }
}
```

could be replace by:

```
memcpy(array, array1[2], sizeof(array1[2]));
```

Accordingly this one:

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<cols;j++) {
    array[3*rows*cols+i*cols+j]=array4[2][i][j];
  }
}
```

is going to be:

```
memcpy(array + 3*cols*rows, array4[2], sizeof(array4[2]));
```

Comment: there are a number of mistakes in this answer, for the first example you copy from `array[2]` to `array` instead of `array1[2]` to `array`, also `memcpy(array + 3*cols*rows, array4[2], sizeof(array));` is guaranteed to write out of bounds, and the first example is guaranteed to read out of bounds as the op stated that `array` is allocated statically with a size of `[4*rows*cols]`

Comment: @Joe: Thanks for pointing me to my typo regarding the wrong source in example 1. Fixed. Also when I wrote the first example I assumed `array` to be `[rows][cols]`. Which would make the 2nd exampe break. I also fixed this. Thanks also on this.

Answer (score 0):

C specifies arrays are stored in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), so each `i` wrapping every `j` (and each `j` wrapping every `k`, and so on) is going to be faster than the alternative due to "[locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)."

However, as mentioned in comments, `memcpy()` will copy the entire space linearly, ignoring the ordering.  So, it's almost certainly no worse and it will be far easier to keep straight, with only one call.  Just be sure to use `sizeof()` to get the size of the array as stored, since the actual storage may be larger than just `rows*cols`.

The only case where `memcpy()` *might* be worse is if your array elements are pointers to something else.  At that point, you would only be copying the map to the real data, which may not be what you want.