# MPI communicate large two dimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, mpi

Related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541623/fastest-way-to-copy-several-2-dimensional-arrays-into-one-1-dimensional-array-i/22542543#22542543) concerning copying of 2- into 1-dimensional arrays, I wondered if there was an even better way to do the whole business, I try to achieve. So, I want to MPI communicated a couple of large two dimensional arrays (which are allocated dynamically as arrays of arrays, but with known size at compile time) from the master to the clients and vice versa. The data is supposed to be scattered to/gathered from the clients column-wise.

What I am doing at the moment is to map the 2-dimensional arrays (which are in fact sub-arrays of 3-dimensional ones) into statically allocated 1-dimensional arrays, send these 1-dim. arrays via MPI and then rebuild the 2-dimensional arrays again at the receiver. However, I have the feeling that there should be something (much) more efficient than that...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why to use arrays of arrays of arrays at all? If they are for "syntactical sugar" only, get rid of them, *now*. You are optimizing, parallelizing - that's the first step to go: no copies, better usage of caches, possibility to use linear algebra libraries...

Comment: @Sigismondo I cant agree with you there, say you were using arrays as a table of know dimensions, would you rather look up foo[3][4] or *(foo + 3 * width + 4)? What is the advantage of not using 2d arrays? Second, if the asker is using MPI they need to use copies, MPI often has no shared memory between processes, they may be on different machines with no way to double map memory between them.

Comment: @Vality. the problem with C is that foo[3][4] means *(*(foo+3)+4) when using arrays of arrays and *(foo +3*width +4) when using 2D static arrays. the second one **is** better, is what all the optimized linear algebra libraries do (ATLAS, libgoto), is what languages supporting multidimensional arrays do (Fortran). Only problem with C is that it doesn't have support for multidimensional dynamic arrays. But arrays of arrays are not the same of 2D arrays.

Comment: @Sigismondo Thanks for that response, it is really interesting to see how that would work. I am interested to see if any common compilers manage to optimize this significantly in the case of static compile time dimensions. However I do see your point that being explicit will force it to use the most efficient way, thanks.

Comment: @Vality. actually I am wrong... C89 have not support for dynamic multidimensional arrays. But C99 **DOES** support multidimensional dynamic arrays - time to stop using a[i*n+j] for me too - adding an answer below. Thanks to you for letting me look for this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C99 has support for dynamic multidimensional arrays: using them you can avoid to copy your data at all. For example the following code does compile with `gcc -std=c99`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int m = atoi(argv[1]);
  int n = atoi(argv[2]);
  int p = atoi(argv[3]);

  // if defined in stack... actually I'm not sure it's defined in stack
  // in this way - shouldn't its size be known at compile time?
  // float a[m][n][p];
  // in heap:
  float (*a)[n][p] = malloc(m*n*p*sizeof(float));
  for (int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
      for (int k=0; k<p; ++k) {
        a[i][j][k] = 100.*i + 10.*j + k;
      }
    }
  }
  for (int i=0; i<m; ++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; ++j) {
      for (int k=0; k<p; ++k) {
        if (k>0) printf(",");
        printf("%7.2f", a[i][j][k]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  free(a);
}
```

(execute with `./a.out 2 3 4`  for example - no error checking... be patient please).

If using C89, when looking for optimized code I think you should sacrifice syntax for the best memory layout, and I would write the same code as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR(A,i,j,k) ((A).a[(i)*A.p*A.n + (j)*A.p + (k)]) 

struct Arr3d {
  float *a;
  int m;
  int n;
  int p;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct Arr3d a;
  int m,n,p;
  int i,j,k;

  m = a.m = atoi(argv[1]);
  n = a.n = atoi(argv[2]);
  p = a.p = atoi(argv[3]);
  a.a = malloc(m*n*p*sizeof(float));
  for (i=0; i<m; ++i) {
    for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
      for (k=0; k<p; ++k) {
        ARR(a,i,j,k) = 100.*i + 10.*j + k;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i=0; i<m; ++i) {
    for (j=0; j<n; ++j) {
      for (k=0; k<p; ++k) {
        if (k>0) printf(",");
        printf("%7.2f", ARR(a,i,j,k));
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  free(a.a);
}
```

In both ways the arrays locations are contiguous in memory and can be sent with a single MPI communication:

```
MPI_Send(&a[0][0][0], m*n*p, MPI_FLOAT, ...       (c99)
MPI_Send(&ARR(a,0,0,0), m*n*p, MPI_FLOAT, ...     (c89)
```

Or as you asked, to send the i-th subarray:

```
MPI_Send(&a[i][0][0], n*p, MPI_FLOAT, ...         (c99)
MPI_Send(&ARR(a,i,0,0), n*p, MPI_FLOAT, ...       (c89)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the array dimensions are known at compile time, e.g. static dimensions are used, then it is as simple as allocating a linear array and then using a pointer cast to a type that corresponds to the multidimensional array shape. For example, for a 3x5 integer array, i.e.

```
int array[3][5];
```

you could instead use:

```
int (*array)[5] = malloc(3*5*sizeof(int));
```

The `int (*)[5]` type is a pointer to an integer array of 5 elements. `array[0]` is the first such 5-element array and `array[0][3]` is the fourth element of the first array.

You can do it with 3-dimensional arrays too.

```
int array[3][4][5];
```

becomes:

```
int (*array)[4][5] = malloc(3*4*5*sizeof(int));
```

For arrays of size that is only known at runtime, a different technique is usually used. One allocates a huge chunk of memory and then builds a tree of pointers into it. So instead of

```
int **array = malloc(3*sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   array[i] = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
```

which usually gives you non-contiguous data storage, you would do:

```
int *array_storage = malloc(3*5*sizeof(int));
int **array = malloc(3*sizeof(int *));
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   array[i] = &array_storage[i*5];
```

The storage is now contiguous. One pitfall of that technique is that one has to use two calls to `free()` in order to deallocate the array:

```
free(array[0]); // Since array[0] == array_storage this frees the big chunk
free(array);    // Frees the array of pointers
```

Instead of allocating two separate dynamic storages, the place for the array of pointers can be allocated together with the data storage and then a single `free(array);` will dispose everything.